# How can i switch from SKScene to UIView

Tags: uiview, storyboard, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite kit framework to create a game.
My first scene is MyScene.My Scene is a menu, but i want when is clicked on start to switch to the first view from the story board.

This is the way i switch to another SKScene

```
Scene001 *start = [[Scene001 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] duration:0.5];
        [self.scene.view presentScene: start transition: reveal];
```

Now the question is how to switch to the storyboard scene and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Are you asking how to cast the UIView of a viewController on the storyboard as a SKView? Or are you asking how to transition from a SKScene back to a UIViewController?

Comment: I created sprite-kit based app.Now i want to make transition to scene from the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but just incase someone comes across it and needs an answer:

What I did in my game was make my GameViewController be a delegate of the SKScene. When the user is finished in the SKScene, I called my delegate function in the GameViewController which simply does a performSegueWithIdentifier. 
Your viewController that creates your scene has can run segue's. So you need a way to get back to it from your SKScene. Simply make your SKScene a delegate and when your viewController creates it, set the delegate. Then when you want to switch, call the delegate function.

This is my GameViewController that creates my scene:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

        if (!skView.scene) {  
            MyScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
            scene.delegate = self;
            [skView presentScene:scene];
        }
    }

 // A delegate function
    - (void)onExitGame {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToNextScene" sender:self];
    }
```

Then from my MyScene when you're ready to switch the storyboard call the delegate function:

```
if (self.delegate) {
  self.delegate.onExitGame();
}
```